# Is there an app for searching through PDFs using images?

Tags: pdf, search, image-recognition, image

I have a bunch of PDFs with images, symbols etc., all black and white if that helps, and using text to search through them is not possible. I have an image of a part of the document that I want.

Is there anyway to search the PDF files using an image?

Edit:
So I thought, if I convert all the PDF files to images and put the outputs to separate folders, is it possible for a template-matching program or something similar to do what I want? I tried doing this myself using python but it takes a long time just search through a single PDF, let alone multiple. Perhaps there is a program that is optimized to do this, search through multiple folders of images, find the image containing part of the image I have, and gives the closest matching result?

I want the program to take into account slight scaling and/or stretching of the photo, look through folders recursively for images, since each of the PDF image outputs will be in separate folders (an image will contain one page of the PDF), and those folders may or may not be in more folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/ocrmypdf/OCRmyPDF):

```
brew install ocrmypdf
ocrmypdf --redo-ocr <old file> <new file>
```

Next option is: [PDFGear](https://www.pdfgear.com/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=comments)

Finally you can try also: [getsearchablepdf](http://getsearchablepdf.com/)